# Can phpstan detect "Typed property ... must not be accessed before initialization" Errors?

Tags: php, phpstan

I have a PHP program,

```
<?php
class Zap {
}

class Zip {
    public Zap $zap;
}
$object = new Zip;

var_dump(
    $object->zap
);
```

This program produces an error because of an initialized non-nullable property.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property Zip::$zap must not be accessed before initialization in

Can `phpstan` detect these sorts of errors?  I've scanned this program at the highest level, and `phpstan` seems happy

```
% ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --level=8 /tmp/test.php
 1/1 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%


                                                                                                                        
 [OK] No errors
```

If `phpstan` can't detect these situations, is there another PHP Static Analyzer that can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the ability to scan for uninitialized property values [was added in July of 2020](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object/issues/129)

However, this feature is disabled by default. You'll need to be using a configuration file that sets the `checkUninitializedProperties` value

```
% cat phpstan.neon 
parameters:
    checkUninitializedProperties: true

and then tell `phpstan` to use this configuration file.

 % ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --level=8 --configuration=./phpstan.neon /tmp/test.php
 1/1 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%

 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Line   /tmp/test.php                                                                                         
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  6      Class Zip has an uninitialized property $zap. Give it default value or assign it in the constructor.  
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

                                                                                                                
 [ERROR] Found 1 error
```

Also, at the risk of saying the obvious part loud, this check assumes a particular style of programming.  For example, the following valid PHP program

```
<?php
class Zap {
}

class Zip {
    public Zap $zap;
}
$object = new Zip;
$object->zap = new Zap;
var_dump(
    $object->zap
);
```

Still fails the `checkUninitializedProperties` check.